# Update 'Enable' of 'asp:DropDownList' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have 2 DropDownLists, and I am trying to switch the second one to Enable=true, When in the first DropDownList I have choose option number 2.

When I run the code on VS, I receive this error:
"JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'setAttribute' of undefined or null reference"

```js
<script language="javascript">
    function Test(ddlId) {

        var ControlName = document.getElementById(ddlId.id);
        if (ControlName.value == 2) {
            alert("good");
            document.getElementById("ddlActivitiesParams2").setAttribute("Enable", true);
            //document.getElementById("ddlActivitiesParams2").disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

```html
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Param1">
    <HeaderStyle Width="25%"></HeaderStyle>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="25%"></ItemStyle>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblParam1Desc" runat="server" Text='' Width="90%" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAgentParams" onchange="Test(this);" DataValueField="Value" DataTextField="Text" DataSource=' <%# GetThresholdsAgentTypeParams() %> ' runat="server" Width="90%">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Param2">
    <HeaderStyle Width="25%"></HeaderStyle>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="25%"></ItemStyle>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblParam2Desc" runat="server" Text='aaa' Width="90%" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlActivitiesParams2" Enabled="false" Visible="true" DataValueField="Value" DataTextField="Text" DataSource=' <%# GetActivities() %> ' runat="server" Width="90%">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: The attribute 'Enable' does not exists at runtime, only in the design. That is why JavaScript gives an error. Just look at the HTML source and you will see that it is not present.

Comment: Ok, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Something like this: `document.getElementById("<%=DropDownList1.ClientID %>").disabled = true;`. You have to get the ID generated for the element you want to disable into javascript.

Comment: You mean: "<%=ddlActivitiesParams2.ClientID %>" ? Because if yes, I have an error.

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'ddlActivitiesParams2' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the wrong ID. ASP.Net client-side ID'S will change at runtime. You can't use a server side block in your selector because the control you're trying to access is within another control.

Being that your ddl is in a footer template, I'm assuming there is only one of them. If this is true and youre using a version of ASP.Net that supports it, you can put the attribute `ClientIDMode="static"` on the ddl, and the ID will not change at runtime.

Otherwise, you may just want to add a unique cssclass to the drop down and select it based on class instead of ID.

Answer (score 0):

It is often the case that containers change the id of controls in the rendering process.
Do a view source on the returned HTML and check what is the id of the created select element